# Search for MAC Manufacturer information using /var/lib/ieee-data/oui.txt

Tags: linux, bash, ieee

I am trying to automatically detect the manufacturers of WiFi cards so that a user can easily decide which card to put into monitormode. `$manu0` won't output any information , What is wrong with `oui.txt` ?

```
        ifconfig > $tmp00
    mac0=$(cat $tmp00 |grep -A4 "^${int}"|grep 'ether'|grep -o '..:'|cut -d ':' -f 1|printf "%s" $(sed -e '4,10d;11q'))
    echo $mac0
    manu0=$(cat /var/lib/ieee-data/oui.txt| grep -i '^${mac0}'|cut -d ' ' -f 7)
#attempt to echo variables    
echo $int && echo $manu0
#attempt to echo variables with string
echo "${int} is a  ${manu0}"
```

OUTPUT:

```
acfdce
wlan0

wlan0 is a
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: `grep -i '$var'` will not work because single quotes prevent expansion of the variable. Use double quotes there.

Comment: `grep ... | grep ... | grep ... | cut ... | printf ... sed` looks like an anti-pattern that you could avoid with `awk`.